# How can I update the properties of a slice of structs within another struct?

Tags: go, pointers, struct

I have a `Jobs` struct which includes a slice of structs of type `Job`. I want to iterate over each `Job` and "execute" them, updating their status in the process.

Code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Job struct {
    id     int
    status string
}

type Jobs struct {
    jobs []Job
}

func main() {
    jobs := Jobs{}

    job := Job{id: 1, status: "pending"}

    jobs.load(job)

    job2 := Job{id: 2, status: "pending"}

    jobs.load(job2)

    fmt.Println(jobs) // jobs should be pending

    jobs.execute()

    fmt.Println(jobs) // jobs should be executing
}

func (j *Jobs) load(job Job) {
    j.jobs = append(j.jobs, job)
}

func (j *Jobs) execute() {
    for _, job := range j.jobs {
        if err := job.execute(); err != nil {
            id := strconv.Itoa(job.id)
            fmt.Println("error occurred when executing job #" + id)
        }
    }
}

func (j *Job) execute() error {
    j.status = "executing"
    fmt.Println("Executing job")

    // return errors.New("error when executing job")

    return nil
}
```

Output when run:

```
{[{1 pending} {2 pending}]}
Executing job
Executing job
{[{1 pending} {2 pending}]}
```

Expected output:

```
{[{1 pending} {2 pending}]}
Executing job
Executing job
{[{1 executing} {2 executing}]}
```

I imagine I have a pointer missing somewhere but I just can't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change how jobs are stored:

```golang
type Jobs struct {
    jobs []*Job
}
```

Then use pointers everywhere in the code:

```golang
func (j *Jobs) load(job *Job) {
    j.jobs = append(j.jobs, job)
}
```

```
jobs := Jobs{}

job := &Job{id: 1, status: "pending"}
jobs.load(job)

job2 := &Job{id: 2, status: "pending"}
jobs.load(job2)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
for _, job := range j.jobs {
```

Inside the loop, `job` is a local variable that contains *a copy of* the element from the slice. So when you modify it, it modifies the copy, *not* the value inside the slice. To get around this, you'd need to either take a pointer to the slice element itself (`&j.jobs[i]`) or make `jobs` a slice of pointers instead of a slice of values. The latter is probably more clear to someone else reading it, because seeing a slice of pointers, they'll be expecting those values to be updated by functions running against them.

There's also a general idiom in Go that when a type's methods use pointer receivers, that implies that the "normal" way to use that type is with pointers. Here you've defined a type with pointer receivers, but you're using values, which is a little bit unusual (but certainly not unheard of).